# Self-Replicating Numbers

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence

### Background

For the purpose of this challenge, all numbers and their string representations are assumed to be in *decimal* (base 10). I tried to find proper terminology for this challenge, but I do not think there is any, so I made it up.

A self-replicating number is a number that appears as a substring in any of its multiples up to and including its square, excluding itself. An \$n\$-order self-replicating number appears as a substring in ***exactly \$n\$*** multiples of itself up to its square, including itself. All numbers are *at least* 1st-order self-replicating numbers, because they appear as a substring in their first multiple (1 times the number).

For example: 5 is a 3rd-order self-replicating number, because it appears 3 times in the multiples of itself up to its square: **5**, <strike>10</strike>, 1**5**, <strike>20</strike>, 2**5**. On the other hand, 4 is a 1st-order self-replicating number, because it appears only once: **4**, <strike>8</strike>, <strike>12</strike>, <strike>16</strike>.

There are only 6 1st-order replicators, because numbers will always have a self-replicator order \$\geq\lfloor\log_{10}(x)\rfloor+1\$, where \$x\$ is the number, as multiples of the number and any power of ten are guaranteed to have the number as a substring. Because of this property of self-replicating numbers, the series of \$n\$-order self-replicating numbers cannot ever be an infinite series. The last possible \$n\$-order self-replicating number is \$10^n-1\$.

### The Challenge

Your task is to write a program which takes two integers, \$m\$ and \$n\$, and does one of the following:

- return the first \$m\$ \$n\$-order self-replicating numbers **\$or\$**
- return the \$m^{th}\$ \$n\$-order self-replicating number (0 or 1-indexed, your choice) **\$or\$**
- output the series of numbers that are either \$m\$-order or \$n\$-order self-replicating numbers. You may treat this series as if it were infinite; in other words, your code is not required to halt - it'd be very cool if it did, though. **\$or\$**
- By popular demand, and because the previous option was a source of valid misinterpretation, you may now instead take a single integer, \$n\$, and output the series of \$n\$-order self-replicating numbers. As with the last option, you may treat the series as if it were infinite.

### Rules

- You are allowed undefined behavior for values of \$m\leq0\$ or \$n\leq0\$.
- Your code is not required to halt if the next number in the sequence does not exist. For example: if you chose either of the first two output options and your code receives \$m=7, n=1\$ as input, a 7th 1st-order self-replicating number will never be found because no 1st-order self-replicating numbers higher than 9 exist.
- Standard loopholes forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest program in bytes for each language wins.

### Test Cases

| \$m\$ | \$n\$ | Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 0 | undefined |
| 6 | 1 | 1,2,3,4,7,9 |
| 7 | 1 | 1,2,3,4,7,9 **\$or\$** undefined |
| 20 | 2 | 6,8,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,21,22,23,24,26,27,29,31 |
| 30 | 4 | 30,45,48,52,55,59,68,69,82,94,110,115,122,128,130,136,137,139,144,145,152,168,170,171,176,177,184,187,190,192 |
| 10 | 38 | 650,3520,3680,3920,6050,6350,6840,7640,7880,7960 |
| 3 | 101 | 7125,8900,9920 |
| 1 | 2778 | 5000 |

Comment: The 3rd output option is rather unusual. Can't we just take \$n\$ and print the corresponding terms forever?

Comment: @Arnauld When I was looking at other sequence challenges for help writing this one, I found that the 'output infinitely' option was the most popular, by a wide margin. I wanted to add a little twist to encourage different output options. That said, I recognize not all my ideas are good ones - so if there is clear support for your proposed change, I'll happily make it.

Comment: Fwiw, I think the standard option that Arnauld suggested makes much more sense.

Comment: @Arnauld your comment along with some answers misinterpreting the third point swayed my opinion. Thanks for helping to improve the challenge for all!

Comment: @Wasif Sorry, poor choice of wording. It should have read "I think it'd be cool if.."

Comment: https://oeis.org/A342468

Comment: @bigyihsuan wow, thanks for doing the work to get this into oeis, that's super amazing!!!

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
1ẇⱮ×R$SƊ=¥#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9qZWxsef//MeG6h@KxrsOXUiRTxoo9wqUj////Mv8yMA)

Takes \$n\$ then \$m\$ on the command line and outputs the first \$m\$ \$n\$-order self-replicating numbers

### How it works

```
1ẇⱮ×R$SƊ=¥# - Main link. Takes n on the left
         ¥  - Group the previous 2 links into a dyad f(k, n):
       Ɗ    -   Group the previous 3 links into a monad on k:
     $      -     Group the previous 2 links into a monad on k:
    R       -       Yield the range [1, 2, ..., k]
   ×        -       Multiply each element by k
  Ɱ         -     For each element i in [k, 2k, ..., k²]:
 ẇ          -       Is k a substring of i?
      S     -     Sum; Count the 1s
        =   -   Does this equal n?
1         # - Count up k = 1, 2, 3, ... until m such k return true under f(k, n)
```

Comment: Nice! I really feared I'd made a challenge that these golfing languages would have a 2-byter for - to get 11 whole bytes out of Jelly, I'm overjoyed.

Comment: @ZaelinGoodman Just wait, I'm sure Jonathan Allan or Kevin Cruijssen will produce a magic 7 or 8 byte version in Jelly or 05AB1E :P

Comment: It just wouldn't be CodeGolf if they didn't put us all to shame on a regular basis :)

Comment: @ChartZBelatedly I think you're overestimating my golfing abilities, haha. I did outgolf you by a single byte with my 05AB1E answer, though. ;)

Answer (score 7):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/),  <s>76 67</s>  66 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @user81655*

A function expecting \$n\$ and printing the \$n\$-order self-replicating numbers forever.

```javascript
n=>{for(m=0;k=++m;s||print(m))for(s=n;k;)s-=!!(k--*m+'').match(m)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCoAgEADAt3jSTYwOHQLZ/iKCZLImKl6yt1udZ07TTLHZp6raNhyOiPvtriwIFx1QStKl95R9rIIAfikYddBQFDImglITSc5hJlPt8Z1nOLHCeAE)

#### Commented

```javascript
n => {                   // n = input
  for(                   // infinite outer loop:
    m = 0;               //   start with m = 0
    k = ++m;             //   before each iteration, increment m and copy it in k
                         //   (always truthy, so we never exit the loop)
    s || print(m)        //   after each iteration, print m if s = 0
  )                      //
    for(                 //   inner loop:
      s = n;             //     start with s = n
      k;                 //     stop when k = 0
    )                    //
      s -=               //     decrement s if ...
        !!(k-- * m + '') //       ... k * m coerced to a string
        .match(m)        //       contains m (decrement k afterwards)
}                        // end
```

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>58</s> 55 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to Dominic van Essen

```r
n=scan();repeat if(sum(grepl(F,(F=F+1)*1:F))==n)show(F)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8@2ODkxT0PTuii1IDWxRCEzTaO4NFcjHcjN0XDT0XCzddM21NQytHLT1LS1zdMszsgv13DT/G/yHwA)

Prints all the \$n\$-order self-replicating numbers.

Comment: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8@2ODkxT0PTuii1IDWxRCEzTaO4NFcjHcjN0XDT0XCzddM21NQytHLT1LS1zdMszsgv13DT/G/yHwA)... I think...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 47 bytes

```
(>:@][echo@]^:(e.~1#.1*@#.]E.&":"0]+]*i.))^:_&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NeysHGKjU5Mz8h1i46w0UvXqDJX1DLUclPViXfXUlKyUDGK1Y7Uy9TQ146zMTA3VDP9rcqUpmCgYW/wHAA)

Third option for output.

TIO has +2 since I changed infinity `_` to 651 to make it clear that it works.

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 17 bytes

Generates the sequence for a given \$n\$.

```
≤≜.{≥.;?×s?∧≜}ᶜ?∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pf/ahtw6Ompoe7Omsfblvw/1Hnkkedc/SqH3Uu1bO2Pzy92P5Rx3KgCFByDoj5/78JAA)

```
≤≜.{≥.;?×s?∧≜}ᶜ?∧
≤≜                 a number k greater-equal than n
  .                is the output
   {         }ᶜ    count the outputs of the predicate,
               ?   unify with n
                ∧  return the output

    ≥              a number less-equal than k
     .             is the output
      ;?×          multiplied by k
         s?        has k as substring
           ∧≜      return the output
```

Comment: Brachylog seems very well-suited for sequence questions like this.

Comment: @Jonah Indeed, practically every predicate is a generator. Sometimes with just one output value. :-)

Comment: Doesn't seem like that second `≜` should be necessary, or even necessarily do anything--so it's really weird how it breaks if you remove it

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 19 bytes

```
ＩΦＸχ⌈θ№θＬΦι№Ｉ×ι⊕λＩι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwy0zpyS1SCMgvxxIGhroKPgmVmTmluZqFGpq6ig455cCFRbqKPik5qWXZMBUZ8JkwEaEZOamFoPEPPOSi1JzU/NKUlM0cjTB@kHymZpQYP3/f3S0oY6CUWzsf92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes a pair (actually any list) of integers `[n, m]` as input and outputs all self-replicating numbers of those order(s), but somewhat slow so avoid using it at all really. Explanation:

```
   χ                Predefined variable 10
  Ｘ                 Raised to power
     θ              Input integers
    ⌈               Maximum
 Φ                  Filter implicit range where
       θ            Input integers
      №             Contains
        Ｌ           Length of
          ι         Current value
         Φ          Filter implicit range where
              ι     Outer value
             ×      Multiplied by
                λ   Inner index
               ⊕    Incremented
            Ｉ       Cast to string
           №        Contains
                  ι Outer value
                 Ｉ  Cast to string
Ｉ                   Cast to string
                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 81 bytes

outputs the series of n-order self-replicating numbers forever

```
Do[Tr@Boole@StringContainsQ[(T=ToString)/@Array[m#&,m],T@m]==#&&Print@m,{m,∞}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773yU/OqTIwSk/PyfVIbikKDMv3Tk/ryQxM684MFojxDYkHyKoqe/gWFSUWBmdq6ymkxurE@KQG2trq6ymFgCULXHI1anO1XnUMa82Vu0/WETBIT3a2CL2/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 72 bytes

```python
def f(n,i=1):
 if sum(`i`in`i*~k`for k in range(i))==n:print i
 f(n,i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcsxDoAgDAXQnVN0pOqCIwl3qYlUf4zFoA4uXh0H3/6O51qLja3NWUm9DUiBoyMonffuBQITdO8mWiptBKM62ZI9mFOyeFTYRXD/7QM39SO3Dw)

Trivial answer that loops through the numbers in order and checks if they are self-replicating.

-8 bytes thanks to *dingledooper*

Comment: @Arnauld cool, updated.

Comment: [75 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFNI08n09ZQ06q4NFejuKRII1MzM08BzNCqy9ZMyy9SyFYAihQl5qWnAiU1bW3zbG0LijLzSoA8a7B2bUPN/2kaRpr/AQ)

Comment: And it's [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcsxDoAgDAXQnVN0pOqCIwl3qYlUf4zFoA4uXh0H3/6O51qLja3NWUm9DUiBoyMonffuBQITdO8mWiptBKM62ZI9mFOyeFTYRXD/7QM39SO3Dw) in Python 2.

Comment: I think this works for [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##JcsxDoAgDAXQ3VMwtkJMYCThLhil@pdCCA6eHgff/to77qphzrOIEVKH5DkuBpL7rlchOKyw3oHzdtRHB2VkTklj69BhsPzNep5CgecH "Python 2 – Try It Online"). It counts how many times the number appears as a string in the list representation, which in theory could allow a multiple to contain the number twice and be double counted, but I think this can't happen without going above the square of the number.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 99 bytes

```powershell
param($n)for($x=1;;++$x){$o=0;for($i=$x;$i-le($x*$x);$i+=$x){$o+=("$i"-match"$x")};if($o-eq$n){$x}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzRCsMgEAT/RfZBI0JKH4/7GCmGCKYmttCD4LdfJH3cmWH3@kvts6ZSVPfY4mbxdkttFsIPIu8h7kTlmW6YGULIoaQRTMON4fnfeLYG2YQtfl@rgRjXKS8WNaRjnJ6Q3lX1eQE)

A script expecting \$n\$ and printing the first \$n\$-order self-replicating numbers forever.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 77 bytes

```powershell
param($m,$n)for(;$n*($m-=$z)){,++$i*($z=(1..$i|?{$i*$_-match$i}).Count-eq$n)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLJjtNAEL37K0rBoJgpR@5ub60oMCgCaQ7JIDI3hEaepMMYecOLQMn428Ozk8CFQ1fX@l5Vqaryl6mbZ5NlJ3tPCzqeqqRO8qmds104@7Kezu3iLUx3YR8c58g3N3YK@7CYitnMTl/eH2Hbj26etNtnO@2d2bLsitY1P1Hfn3rLup1aFhFPAybynFENoQo8CMmKfY5YO9YrRKL/RKisqSt2Zp8WZueQ@47uCuhpaygry2pElB6THOpCjll4LAQLyUKx8FkELEIWEQuENEtAS5aKpc8yZBmx1KzEuTMFHH/AgeIH7MccSA4CDjSHMYeaY8kakCMFcIEkJGCRLhRIFFiUBityUC9QLVAoIsQj9BQNjQydIB7j1/BrOczeliXGKb4Tlk4Pd/fjOkBDKkY/YeCxCjClCmMIDS304AvVIGLf4ygcRIxopEPvvE01bNPDPiMhA46157FG6Tk4rFlGESb0PLgsh17oNR2xBiI7LaoVj98an/ldmW1rdjgQ@/GcYLKkakbPyiRNVxt3WeZ5UuwuCGNSbZoua5HzBsc1Yp4hx4x@lF8/b5Zd05b5/dMPcHy7PdLHv9BXljmtBmsAmNP6oq7ntOm2W9M0cEwuXBPC5cG6djyZ05drE/9yeqvHsJ/KGlfrPiRPmSH3Q9eWm/RgTn8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞ʒL¤*¬δåOQ
```

Uses the last option: given an integer \$n\$, outputs the infinite (non-halting) sequence of \$n\$-order self-replicating numbers.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8U5N8KrUqz205vNQ/8P9/EwA) or [verify for the first `n=[0,20]` inputs all output-values below 1000](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9kcGyS36GVnkr@pSUFpSXFCkmpOfnlCof3K6TlFylk5gHFFPJsD@@3UlDS@e9zapJPpVbluS2Hl/ofWhf4v1bn0Db7/4YGBgYA).

**Explanation:**

```python
∞           # Push an infinite list of positive integers: [1,2,3,...]
 ʒ          # Filter each integer `y` by:
  L         #  Push a list in the range [1,y]
   y*       #  Multiply each by `y`
      δ     #  Map over each value in this list:
     y å    #   Check if it contains `y` as substring
        O   #  Sum this list together to get the amount of truthy values
         Q  #  And check if this is equal to the (implicit) input-integer `n`
            # (after which the filtered infinite list is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 18 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Èõ*X è_s øXÃ¥V}jU1
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=yPUqWCDoX3Mg%2bFjDpVZ9alUx&input=MzAKMg)

- we could save a byte by returning nth term 0 indexed just by using `iU` instead of `jU1` but this way is more easy to validate output.

```
    È ...}jU1 - first n terms
    õ*X       - multiples to X^2
    è .. ¥V   - number of multiples returning true to _ 'function (Z)'== second input?
    _s øXÃ    - convert to string and check if contains X
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 67 bytes

```
n=>Stream.from(1)filter(x=>x.to(x*x,x).count(_+""contains ""+x)==n)
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/TdeAc7aBRCu8PflS4j3sPQ) (ignore the deprecation warnings)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 27 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
{⍸⍵=(1⊥⊢(1∊⍷⍥⍕)¨⊢×⍳)¨⍳10*⍵}
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=q37Uu@NR71ZbDcNHXUsfdS0C0h1dj3q3P@pd@qh3quahFUCxw9Mf9W4GMXs3GxpoAVXXAgA&f=S1MwAgA&i=AwA&r=tryAPL&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

A dfn submission which takes \$n\$ and prints all self-replicating numbers of order \$n\$ and terminates.

**Commented:**

```apl
{⍸⍵=(...)¨⍳10*⍵}   ⍝ dfn which takes n as a right argument and returns all nth-order self-replicating numbers
          ⍳10*⍵    ⍝ the indices from 1 to 10^n
    (...)¨         ⍝ for each number, calculate the order of self-replication
  ⍵=               ⍝ is this order equal to n?
 ⍸                 ⍝ the indices of all 1's 

(1⊥⊢(1∊⍷⍥⍕)¨⊢×⍳)   ⍝ train that takes a number k as a right argument and returns the order
            ⊢×⍳    ⍝ k × (1 2 ... k) = (k×1 k×2 ... k×k)
   ⊢( ... )¨       ⍝ for each value as a right argument and k as a left argument:
     1∊⍷           ⍝ is the left argument is a substring of the right after ...
        ⍥⍕         ⍝ ... both are formatted as a string
 1⊥                ⍝ sum all results
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>160</s> 154 bytes

```python
def am(m,n):
 k=lambda n:[i*n for i in range(1,n+1)if str(n)in str(i*n)];l=[];i=1
 while len(l)<m:
  q=k(i)
  if len(q)==n:l.append(q[0])
  i+=1
 return l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU5LDoIwEN1zill2pDEUExdgT0JY1FBkQjuUWmM8fS0u3L1/XvikZeNLzpOdwXjhJWNXwaqd8ffJAHcDnRjmLQIBMUTDDyuU5FohzfBMUTAW/QAliGPv9DD2pFUF74WcBWdZOLz5sgq7XgVhAaV66DtqzZ07mxAsT2IfmvHn1kc92vSKDC6HSJxEOXeVCrH607aRLWL@Ag)

Comment: You have a lot of extra whitespace and newlines that can be removed by putting things on the same line using `;`, or in the case of the `if`, just getting rid of the space altogether.

Comment: Also `am` could be one character shorter.

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 96 bytes

```kotlin
fun f(n:Int)=generateSequence(1){it+1}.filter{x->(x..x*x step x).count{"$it".contains("$x")}==n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc7NCsIwDAfwu09Rxg6tYtmHOBHm3fN8gTGyUTfTuWVQKH32WWR60MNyCsmP5N9q6hTOcz0hqzmer0gibwBhKAkKeE6AFfBYWEW72MladQSDNfsLN1KarWEjQc@MkJWekGwQKgp8j1QqHHkQmkC4PEf3fvDwQy6Y3TBf/aCQOuS1vy6pbIEfhbxrhTddkN81XIgfmCwwidbkYZHpqkxPC41XaRx9kqarSbPse/ffuvkF)

Returns the sequence of all \$n\$-order self-replicating numbers